# how to patch changes to an rpm file

Tags: patch, rpm, rhel

I have a third party rpm (*rabbitmq-server-3.5.4-noarch.rpm*) and I need to make some text changes on a static-file (a text file) in this rpm as per my organization policy.
I need to make changes before installing it on my server. Could someone guide me to do this.

I tried *rpm2cpio* command but was only able to see the contents displayed on the console, but I need to make the changes to the text inside the rpm.

Comment: This is a bad idea all around... first, you shouldn't be changing somebody else's license; it's most likely not yours to decide. Second, RPMs are signed explicitly to *stop* you from patching them.

Comment: Thanks, but the changes are on the opensource license description files which is used by this rpm. And got to know it is legal to modify the license text as per their advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

afaik there is no way to patch an rpm as such. I would recommend to:

- get the source rpm (.src.rpm)
- install the source rpm
- patch your license text file
- rebuild a new rpm (preferably with another version number)

Comment: Thanks!!, yes this worked, was able to generate both srpm and the binary, but the version numbering has some additional characters. The newly built rpm "rabbitmq-server-3.5.4-2.el6.noarch.rpm" has 'el6' characters after the version#. don't know from where this is coming from.
Also observerd in the .spec file I see Release: 2%{?dist}, might be "{?dist} is that 'el6'.

Comment: Inderdaad the Total name Comes from name-version-release... Hierover IT is a good thing to differentiate the RPM you generated from the original one, so some extra letter, or numbers are perfect. This doesn't alter the way the RPM works...

Comment: You're welcome. If my answer helped you, please consider accepting this answer so others see that your question is solved...